# I'm trying to scrape a website for some list items, but beautiful soup does not find any on the page

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to make a table where I collect all the works of each composer from [this page](https://halloffame.classicfm.com/2019/) and arrange them by adding "score" e.g. 1 point for 300th place, 290 points for 10th place, etc. using a Python script.

However, BeautifulSoup does not seem to find the `li` elements. What am I doing wrong? A screenshot of the page HTML: https://gyazo.com/73ff53fb332755300d9b7450011a7130

I have already tried using `soup.li`, `soup.findAll("li")` and `soup.find_all("li")`, but all return "none" or similar. Printing `soup.body` does return the body though, so I think I do have an HTML document.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import requests

link = "https://halloffame.classicfm.com/2019/"
response = requests.get(link)
soup = bsoup(response.text, "html.parser")
print(soup.li)
```

I was hoping this would give me at least one `li` item, but instead it returns `None`.

Comment: Have you tried printing `response.text` to see what you're actually getting?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see all rankings from 300-1. Sometimes page shows only to 148, other times to 146, and lowest I have seen is 143. Don't know if this is a design flaw/bug. The page is javascript updated which is why you are getting an empty list. That content hasn't been rendered.

`requests` only returns content that doesn't rely on javascript to render i.e. you don't get everything that you see when using a browser which, if javascript is enabled, will allow additional content to be loaded as various scripts on the page run. This is a feature of modern responsive/dynamic webpages where you no longer have to update an entire page when, for example, selections are made on the page.

Often you can use dev tools <kbd>F12</kbd> to inspect the web traffic the page is using to update the content via the network tab. With the network tab open refresh the entire page and then filter on XHR.

In this case, the info is actually pulled from a script tag which already holds that info. You can open the elements tab (Chrome) and do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and search for a composer's name. You will find one match occurs in a script tag. I use regex to find the script tag this is in by matching on  javascript  `var songs = [];` which is then followed by the object containing the composer info in the following regex group.

Sample from target script tag:

[image]

You can grab these from script tag

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re

soup = bs(requests.get('https://halloffame.classicfm.com/2019/', 'lxml').content, 'lxml')
r = re.compile(r'var songs = \[\];(.*)' , re.DOTALL)
data = soup.find('script', text=r).text
script = r.findall(data)[0].strip()
rp = re.compile(r'position:\s+(\d+)')
rankings = rp.findall(script)     
rt = re.compile(r'title:\s+"(.*)"')
titles = rt.findall(script) 

print(len(titles))
print(len(rankings))
```

If you can locate the rest of these rankings you can then zip your lists whilst reversing the rankings list

```
results = list(zip(titles, rankings[::-1]))
```

Either way, you can use the len of the titles to generate a list of numbers in reverse that will give the rankings:

```
rankings = list(range(len(titles), 0, -1))
results = list(zip(titles, rankings[::-1]))
```

Comment: The list has not been fully released yet, its running over easter, but I´ll try this, thanks!

Comment: It seems to work, but I dont really understand what it means/what the difference is that it is javascript updated? Im new to coding, and Im just not quite sure what the script does, I guess. I understand the re module but Im less versed in beautifulsoup, and how you know what script/data to search.

Comment: Also, running it in pycharm gives the error "no parser was explicitly stated, using html.parser"

Comment: Is this now answered please?